# How to fix python (3.7) UnicodeDecoreError - 'ascii' ... when trying to 'eb init' -> eu-west-2 (or any other)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unicode, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.7

When I try to initialise an elastic beanstalk on my local machine's terminal, I am asked to choose a default option.

I'm particularly interested in initialising for London (eu-west-2), but whenever I do that (or any other) I get the following error.

`ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)`

Having researched a little further, I am guessing this is a python issue when the option I am choosing for London is not read correctly hence giving me the error above.

When trying to run with
`eb init --debug`
it seems like I am python3.7.

I also tried to `brew link python`, but have had no luck so far.

I am not entirely sure how I would fix this issue, has anyone come across this before?

---

Turns out my `botocore` (an AWS-Python SDK) was unable to decode my aws-credentials as it mistakenly had a non-ascii character.

Here is a list of ascii characters incase someone runs to this problem in the future by accident.
https://ascii.cl/

---

Stack Trace before fix:

````
2019-04-15 10:29:40,185 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_setup'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,185 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_setup'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_run'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_run'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_argument_parsing'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_argument_parsing'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_close'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_close'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'signal'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_render'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_render'
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'add_handler_override_options' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_setup']
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'handler_override' from cement.core.foundationinto hooks['post_argument_parsing']
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'extension' (IExtension)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'log' (ILog)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,186 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'config' (IConfig)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'mail' (IMail)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'plugin' (IPlugin)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'output' (IOutput)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'argument' (IArgument)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'controller' (IController)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'cache' (ICache)
2019-04-15 10:29:40,187 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : registering handler '<class 'cement.core.extension.CementExtensionHandler'>' into handlers['extension']['cement']
2019-04-15 10:29:40,205 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /etc/eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2019-04-15 10:29:40,205 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /Users/rahulverma/.eb/plugins.d does notexist.
2019-04-15 10:29:40,211 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- EBCLI Version: 3.14.10
2019-04-15 10:29:40,211 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- Python Version: 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
2019-04-15 10:29:40,212 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/rahulverma
2019-04-15 10:29:40,212 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Directory found, but no config or app name exists

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) cn-northwest-1 : China (Ningxia)
14) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
15) ca-central-1 : Canada (Central)
16) eu-west-2 : EU (London)
17) eu-west-3 : EU (Paris)
18) eu-north-1 : EU (Stockholm)
(default is 3): 16
2019-04-15 10:29:45,858 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Inside get_available_solution_stacks api wrapper
2019-04-15 10:29:45,858 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Session
2019-04-15 10:29:45,859 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore version: 1.12.90
2019-04-15 10:29:45,871 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Client for elasticbeanstalk
2019-04-15 10:29:45,884 (INFO) eb : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebrun.py", line 62, in run_app
    app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 94, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 88, in do_command
    self.region = set_up_credentials(self.app.pargs.profile, self.region, self.interactive)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 562, in set_up_credentials
    profile, region = check_credentials(profile, given_profile, given_region, interactive, force_non_interactive)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 529, in check_credentials
    initializeops.credentials_are_valid()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/initializeops.py", line 27, in credentials_are_valid
    elasticbeanstalk.get_available_solution_stacks(fail_on_empty_response=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elasticbeanstalk.py", line 388, in get_available_solution_stacks
    result = _make_api_call('list_available_solution_stacks')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elasticbeanstalk.py", line 39, in _make_api_call
    **operation_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 193,in make_api_call
    operation = _set_operation(service_name, operation_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 311,in _set_operation
    client = _get_client(service_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 152,in _get_client
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 805, in create_client
    api_version = self.get_config_variable('api_versions').get(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 233, in get_config_variable
    logical_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",line 226, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",line 323, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",line 382, in provide
    config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 324, in get_scoped_config
    profile_map = self._build_profile_map()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 218, in _build_profile_map
    self._profile_map = self.full_config['profiles']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 362, in full_config
    cred_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 149, in raw_config_parse
    cp.read([path])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1014, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)

2019-04-15 10:29:45,885 (INFO) eb : UnicodeDecodeError - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)```
````

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace that you see when you run `eb init --debug`?

Comment: Also, from your shell, can you get the output of `locale charmap`?

Comment: Hi progfan, thanks for getting back. Just added the stack trace with the questions

```locale charmaps``` gives me ```UTF-8```

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is but I strongly suspect the failure is in `botocore` (the AWS Python SDK) as it is trying to parse your `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files. Can you check to ensure those files do not contain non-ASCII characters?

Comment: So you were right! For some reason I had a non-ascii at the end of my credentials!
Perhaps I had made a typo accidentally when whenever I had opened it.

Thank you for your support, I greatly appreciate it.
How were you able to triangulate that the problem may have been there if I may ask?

Comment: Glad you found your problem. Well, looks like you removed the stack trace from your original post. The trace suggested that the exception was being thrown by the piece of code in `botocore` that parses the credentials file.

Comment: Thanks progran, my mistake! I've added the stack trace back again :)